# Some clarity on the arguments of `fexecve`

Tags: c, linux

The Linux man pages say that the third argument to `fexecve` is `envp[]` which my research has led me to believe is the environment to execute the file descriptor e.g. “/use/python3” for a Python file.

1. Is this true? Please correct me if I’m wrong
2. What if I’m using an ELF binary? What would the argument be then?

Note: I’ve tried this with the second and third arguments empty `*char[]` (if that’s what the types were) and I got:

> fexecve: invalid argument

Thanks in advance. I’m doing this on my phone so excuse any weird text. Also, the file descriptor is a memfd, if that means anything.

Comment: The environment is an array of environment variables, e.g. `PATH=...` and `SHELL=...`. You're confusing it with the shebang used to execute scripts.

Comment: "_the environment to execute the file descriptor e.g. “/use/python3” for a Python file._": What do you mean with this? What is `/use/python3` and what does it have to do with environment variables? "_I’ve tried this with the second and third arguments empty_": The `man` page states that the call will fail if either the second or third argument are  `NULL`. They are supposed to point to arrays of strings terminated with null pointers.

Comment: @user17732522 He thinks "environment" means interpreter, as would be found in the `#!` line of a script.

Comment: Sorry, typo. I meant `/usr/bin/python3`. Also, I thought I was wrong, but didn’t know what was right. @Barmar feel free to post an answer so it can be accepted.

Comment: It's the same as the `envp` argument to `execve()`. The only difference between them is that the program to run is identified using a file descriptor rather than a pathname.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `envp` argument is just like the same argument to `execve()` or `execle()`. It's an array of strings, where each element is an environment variable in the format `variable=value`, which will be used as the initial set of environment variables in the new process. The end of the array is indicated by a `NULL` value.

`fexecve()` is the same as `execve()`, except that it gets the program to run from an open file descriptor rather than a pathname; this can be useful to avoid some race conditions resulting from the executable or a directory in its pathname being replaced after an existence check.

The details of the `envp` parameter can be found in the [`execve()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) man page.  If you don't need to provide a custom environment, you can use the global variable [`environ`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html) to have the new process inherit the current process's environment (this is how `execl()` and `execv()` work, since they don't take an explicit `envp` argument).